# bash - wrong answer by word count command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to get the word count of a string using the `wc` command. But it gives me a different answer. It increases the number of words by 1.

This is the code:

```
echo Enter a string:
read str
len=`echo $str | wc -c`
echo you have entered: $str
echo and the word count: $len
```

The output is like this:

```
Enter a string:
robin
you have entered: robin
and word count: 6
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me solve this. I will be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you mean *character count* not word count (which would be 1), the issue is that `echo` adds a newline character. You can either use

```
len=`echo -n $str | wc -c`
```

(the `-n` switch suppresses the newline) or - better - just use the bash `#` variable length operator

```
len=${#str}
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man wc`:

```
-c, --bytes
    print the byte counts

-w, --words
    print the word counts
```

So, you should use `wc -w` instead of `wc -c`.

Comment: You're right, but his question is confusing. I thought he accidently had mistaken `-c` for count.